# What is the Syntax error in this simple Python file?

Tags: python, syntax, terminal

following the Python tutorial on Tuts+ and I'm getting a syntax error in my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

html = urlopen('http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_life.html').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for section in soup.findAll('span',{"class":"bqQuoteLink"})
    print section
    break
```

[image]

The tutorial required me to download and install [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which I did with no errors. The only thing I can think off is that I'm using 4.3 while the tutorial author used 4.1?

Comment: you're missing a colon at the end.

Comment: You forgot the `:` at the end of the for loop statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for section in soup.findAll('span', {"class":"bqQuoteLink"}):
```

... You forgot the `:` at the end of the loop.

Comment: hah! That was it, the tutorial's video cut off the end of his code view in his editor... that was quick :)